# KentorAuth Signing Request XML

Tags: c#, xml, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

Does KentorAuth support signing auth request? I didn't see that, but I see this method:

```
public static void Sign(this XmlDocument xmlDocument, X509Certificate2 cert)
```

Can I use this method to generate valid (properly signed auth request)?

It looks that this is a missing part?

```
 var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
 keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)cert.PrivateKey));

 signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
```

Comment: the keyinfo part was recently added: https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/commit/42f27ec4725d5783f0f9efe68b1c867bd33ecf3e#diff-07c6094237afc811bf52f37e46e3d654 but whether it's directly useable for signed requests I'm not sure

Comment: I must be having some older version than.

Answer (score 1):

AuthServices supports signing AuthnRequests from version 0.15.1

#### Original answer:

There is no support for signing an `AuthnRequest` yet.

The `Sign()` method you've found will correctly add a signature to an XML document, but it isn't enough. The `AuthnRequest` is in most cases transferred with the http redirect binding, which requires the signature to be removed from the actual XML document and put in a separate query string parameter.

Comment: It looks like we'll add support for this within the next few weeks, as part of enabling single logout (which is needed quite urgently for one of our customers)

Comment: You saying that we need SAMLRequest where we put XML content without signature and additional parameter with just a signature node? 

How about if I use http post binding? Same thing?

Comment: Please look at the bindings specification for the details of signature handling. It's the redirect binding that is a bit special.

Comment: It looks it also can depend of IdP. For example, it works for me even without these additional parameters. Not sure if IdP have some fallback to look into SAMLRequest directly to find these parameters or that's how can be configured. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I am curious, did you end up adding support for signed requests? Just saw this: https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/95 - so I guess no

Comment: @PaulB. No, it's not supported yet.